# ExtJS 6.5 View, how to unselect last one selected

Tags: extjs

I've got an Ext.view.View that has a list of templates rendered.  When I select a row on the view, I want the previous one selected to be unselected.  Currently, I have an onchange event that deselects everything (see below), but that causes problems when I have items filtered.

How can I DeSelect just the currently filtered rows.  below is my unselect everything code.

```
        Ext.Array.each(this.query('dataview'), function (v) {
            v !== sm.view && v.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
        });
```

Want I'm wanting is to just deselect the rows that are filtered in the associated store. The problem with the above code is that when it runs, the filter gets removed and all the rows in the view show back up again.

Comment: Not sure what version/toolkit you use. Can you make a fiddle? By default, a view only allows selection of one node, unless [you set the `mode` to multi](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#cfg-mode).

Comment: To answer the question in the heading, which seems not to be the same as the question in the body: [`selModel.deselect(selModel.getLastSelected())`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.selection.Model.html#method-getLastSelected)